# set application time zone dynamically (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I need to set `config.time_zone` according to a record in my database. Inside of rails initialization block, I don't have access to the models because they haven't been loaded yet, I think.

I tried to run the query without the model, with the code below, but the connection is not established yet at this moment.

```
require 'active_record'
timezone = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute
```

Creating a before filter and set Time.zone every request doesn't help me.

Is there a way around this?

**updated:**

figured it out putting this at the end of environment.rb:

```
timezone = SiteConfig.find_by_attribute("timezone").attribute_value
zone_default = Time.__send__(:get_zone, timezone)
Time.zone_default = zone_default
ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_attributes = true
ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = :utc
```

the code was extracted from rails initialization file.